# DynamoDB API: 400 Bad Request without response data

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Last week I worked on the implementation of Signature Version 4 on Javascript (not SDK because I do not like external dependencies). During debugging many times I faced with the error that my signature is incorrect. And now I see the same 400 Bad Request but without response data - so I have no idea what to do with that.

I checked my code and documentation few times.

Below code about signing (maybe will be useful for somebody too as the example of implementation). `storageCache['Credentials']` is the data returned from `AWSCognitoIdentityService.GetCredentialsForIdentity`.

```
async function _updatePlayedStatus(id, val) {

    const dateObj = new Date();

    const body = JSON.stringify({
        'TableName': 'history',
        'Key': {'email': nodes.email.innerText, 'utc': id},
        'UpdateExpression': 'SET isNew = :isNew, updated = :updated',
        'ExpressionAttributeValues': {
            ':isNew': val.toString(),
            ':updated': dateObj.getTime() / 1000 | 0}
    });

    const headers = {
        'Authorization': await _buildAuthorizationHeaderForDynamoDB(
            storageCache['Credentials']['SessionToken'],
            storageCache['Credentials']['SecretKey'],
            storageCache['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
            body,
            dateObj),
        'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.0',
        'x-amz-date': _getDatetimeIn8601Format(dateObj),
        'x-amz-target': 'DynamoDB_20120810.UpdateItem',
        'x-amz-security-token': storageCache['Credentials']['SessionToken']
        /* Without date will be 400 Bad Request.
         * I tried shorter Date instead of x-amz-date but 400 Bad Request
         * com.amazon.coral.service#IncompleteSignatureException

         * 'Authorization header requires existence of either a 'X-Amz-Date' or a 'Date' header.'
         * When 'Date' - I see it in console.debug() but not in request headers.
         */
    };
    console.debug('headers:', headers);
    fetch('https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com', {
        'method': 'POST',
        'headers': headers,
        'body': body
    });
}


/**
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html
 */
async function _buildAuthorizationHeaderForDynamoDB(SessionToken, SecretKey, AccessKeyId, body, dateObj) {
    console.debug('_buildAuthorizationHeaderForDynamoDB args:', arguments);

    /** Task 1: Create a Canonical Request for Signature Version 4
     *  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html */
    const canonicalRequest = `POST
/

content-type:application/x-amz-json-1.0
host:dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
x-amz-date:${_getDatetimeIn8601Format(dateObj)}
x-amz-security-token:${SessionToken}
x-amz-target:DynamoDB_20120810.UpdateItem
content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token;x-amz-target
${await _sha256(body)}`;
    const dateStr = dateObj.toISOString().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, '');
    // YYYYMMDD, for example 20150830

    /** Task 2: Create a String to Sign for Signature Version 4
     *  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-string-to-sign.html */
    const stringToSign = `AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
${_getDatetimeIn8601Format(dateObj)}
${dateStr}/us-east-1/dynamodb/aws4_request
${await _sha256(canonicalRequest)}`;

    /** Task 3: Calculate the Signature for AWS Signature Version 4
    *   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-calculate-signature.html
    *   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/sign */

    const credential = `${AccessKeyId}/${dateStr}/us-east-1/dynamodb/aws4_request`;

    const kDate = await crypto.subtle.sign(
        'HMAC',
        await _importKey(gTextEncoder.encode(`AWS4${SecretKey}`)),
        gTextEncoder.encode(dateStr)
    );

    const kRegion = await crypto.subtle.sign(
        'HMAC',
        await _importKey(kDate),
        gTextEncoder.encode('us-east-1')
    );

    const kService = await crypto.subtle.sign(
        'HMAC',
        await _importKey(kRegion),
        gTextEncoder.encode('dynamodb')
    );

    const kSigning = await crypto.subtle.sign(
        'HMAC',
        await _importKey(kService),
        gTextEncoder.encode('aws4_request')
    );

    const signatureArrayBuffer = await crypto.subtle.sign(
        'HMAC',
        await _importKey(kSigning),
        gTextEncoder.encode(stringToSign)
    );

    const signatureHex = _binaryToHex(Array.from(new Uint8Array(signatureArrayBuffer)));
    // Array.from() because ArrayBuffer does not have the map() method.

    return `AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=${credential}, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token;x-amz-target, Signature=${signatureHex}`;
}


/**
 * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/importKey
 */
async function _importKey(keyDataArrayBuffer) {
    return crypto.subtle.importKey(
        'raw',
        keyDataArrayBuffer,
        {'name': 'HMAC', 'hash': {'name': 'SHA-256'}},
        false,
        ['sign']);
}


/**
 * Function from
 * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest
 */
async function _sha256(message) {

    // encode as UTF-8
    const msgBuffer = gTextEncoder.encode(message);

    // hash the message
    const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', msgBuffer);

    // convert ArrayBuffer to Array
    const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer));

    return _binaryToHex(hashArray);
}


function _binaryToHex(array) {
    return array.map(b => ('00' + b.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');
}


/** Date format is specified with ISO8601 basic format
 * YYYYMMDD'T'HHMMSS'Z'
 * for example
 * 20180112T101849
 */
function _getDatetimeIn8601Format(dateObj) {
    return dateObj.toISOString().replace(/[:-]/g, '').slice(0, 15) + 'Z';
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that you get a `400 Bad Request` response with a `Content-Length: 0` header?

Comment: Hmmm... I found that response `Content-Length` is 254 but also Chrome saying that `This request has no response data available`...

Comment: Testing requests with `curl -v` instead of a browser is usually a solid option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like defect of Google Chrome when `Content-Length` of response is non zero but `Response` tab showing `This request has no response data available`.

`console.log(response)` showed me the same `The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.`. Maybe somebody will notice some problem with my code..

UPDATED: aha, my problem was in [task one](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html) - after canonical headers must be TWO `\n`. In documentation this is shown only in example